# URL_LAUNCHER does not work in Release mode

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know what's going on with my functions at URL_LAUNCHER. In debug mode everything works normal, but in the Release version it is not working. When I press the icon, nothing happens. When I run  `flutter run --release`, I can see that it gives an error:

- with "canLaunch":
  `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method canLaunch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url`
- without "canLaunch":
  `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method launch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher)`

An example of code that is giving this error:

```
onPressed: (){
                launch("tel:${modelComercio.telefone}");
              },
```

Comment: Have you tried flutter clean and then running again?

Comment: Yes. In debug mode it works normal. In release mode it doesn't work ... =/

Comment: Same problem here. Did you fixed it or not?

Comment: @AlanSoares Brother???